# Visual C++ | How to benchmark EVERY FUNCTION and log output?

Tags: c++, performance, profiling, benchmarking

Question in title. I want to know how I can neatly log or see all execution times of each and every function, without actually having to paste the chrono timer stuff into every function ...

Any help in appreciated!

Comment: Profiler???????

Comment: Search your tool-chain documents for "profiler". GCC, clang, MSVS all have one.

Comment: Yes, VS has an excellent profiler, although you might need VS Professional to get it (not sure).

Comment: There are also profilers independent of a specific toolchain like VTune (free for open-source projects and students).